# Regex test, is there a better way to write this?

Tags: javascript, regex, optimization

The following code works, but I wonder if there is a better way to achieve the same result:

```
var regex = /define\((\s+)?['|"](PRIVATE_KEY)['|"],(\s+)?['|"](.*)['|"](\s+)?\)/i;
```

Test:

```
regex.test("define('PRIVATE_KEY', 'MYSECRETKEY');");
```

https://regex101.com/r/pW0qS0/4

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'better'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you don't need to use pip within character class (if you want to match only one quote and double quote) also instead of `(\s+)?` you can use `\s*`:

```
/define\(\s*['"](PRIVATE_KEY)['"],\s*['"](.*)['"]\s*\)/i
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/dL1vF4/3